# Regex to get number after last underscore

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I am having trouble coming up with the regex command that will get me `Y` in the following string `X_X_X_Y` . BTW: Y is an interger, but can validate that after.

Comment: What exactly are you using, bash or sed?  (I'm reasonably sure it's not [nsregularexpression; read the tag's synopsis to see why.)  And what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will work as long at the stuff you're matching for is an integer

```
[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_(\d+)
```

Comment: wouldnt this just return the same value you inputted? How do you extract the last value after the _ based on what you have?

Comment: The () around the group you want capture it as a submatch. Then use bash (http://grulos.blogspot.com/2006/02/bashrematch-regular-expressions.html) or other appropriate tool to get the submatch.

Comment: I guess if I do this (\d+)$ should work also right? Which should give me the last digit in the string.

Comment: Yes. If you know it falls at the end of the line that's an easy approach.

Comment: Ah. it does most of the time. But incase, How can i take that and make it the last number after the underscore. That might be better way to look at it.

Comment: That's what the regex in my answer does. All you need to do is grab the submatch. What language are you using? Is it bash? something else?

Comment: Its Regex, embedded in Nant... I tried that and it just returned back X_X_X_Y... I just tried this "[^_]+(\d+)$" and looks like it may work..Does that look good to you?

Comment: Again, as long as the number you are looking for always lands at the end of the string then \d+$ is good enough.

Comment: If it's this: http://nant.sourceforge.net/nightly/latest/help/tasks/regex.html, then try something like <regex pattern="[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_(?'number'\d+)" input="Whatever your input is including X_X_X_432 whatever" /> <echo message="${number}" />

Answer (score 6):

You could use shell parameter expansion:

```
$ s="X_X_X_Y"
$ echo "${s##*_}"
Y
```

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/.*_//' <<< "$s"
Y
```

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '.*_\K.*' <<< "$s"
Y
```

Comment: !! You are best  1Up for you

Comment: I learned that '<<<' is actually equivalent to `echo $s | sed 's/.*_//'`

Comment: @Ashish `<<<` is referred to as a here-string.

Comment: @Ashish It denotes the option to enable perl compatible regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

as an alternative, if you are always tokenizing on the _ char you can skip regex and use awk

```
echo 'X_X_X_Y' | awk -F_ '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using BASH regex:

```
s='s="X_X_X_10'
[[ "$s" =~ [^_]+$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
10
```

Comment: 1+ to Regex expert again.. :)

Comment: @Ashish: Thanks, I am no where close to an expert, just trying to learn it every day.

Answer (score 0):

This will print an integer at the end of the string after an underscore.

```
 perl -e '"0_0_0_1" =~ /_([0-9]+)$/; print $1,"\n" if defined $1'
1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/.*_\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\1/' file
```